# Meteor JS: Installing on apache/linux server

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, apache, meteor

I have been looking over this tutorial: http://ox86.tumblr.com/post/45184656062/running-your-meteor-js-application-on-your-own-server but having a hard time understanding how it works.

All of my code is in git (on bitbucket.org) so, I can skip the bundling command, but do I need to install Node.js separate from installing Meteor or does installing Meteor take care of that for me?

Comment: That's a rather old tutorial. Follow the docs on [meteor](http://docs.meteor.com/) on how to set it up. It's pretty much `curl https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh`, `cd /app/directory`, `meteor`

Comment: Will this install any packages that need to be installed? I am using meteorite locally

Answer (score 3):

- Meteor requires [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/) (it runs on it), so you need to install NodeJS first.
- Meteor uses [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.org/) so you need to install it as well.
- Next up, install [Meteor](http://meteor.com/) of course. It's on their website.
- You'd need [Meteorite](https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite) for packages, if any.
- Then [bundle and deploy](http://docs.meteor.com/#deploying) your application.

With all that hassle in the tutorial, there are *other ways* to do installation, and is much more easier.

- Deploy to meteor.com. They allow you to host your apps under a subdomain of meteor.com. Then, purchase your own domain name, and have it point to your subdomain:

  > You can also deploy to your own domain. Just set up the hostname you want to use as a CNAME to origin.meteor.com, then deploy to that name.
- Platform-As-A-Service (PAAS). [Heroku](http://heroku.com/) would be a good example. They give you a platform to run your apps, not necessarily just a web server. It's similar to how meteor.com runs. Likewise, you can also purchase a domain name and point to it.
- Virtual Private Server. It's a computer in the cloud. They typically run Linux. You get SSH access to it, and run stuff like you would on the terminal of your PC. This would require a bit more technical stuff. Just added it here for reference.